# What should I use instead of goto statement?

Tags: c

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    random: temp=rand()%9;
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(temp==randarr[j])
        {
            goto random;
        }
    }
    randarr[i]=temp;
       //   printf("%d ",randarr[i]);
}
```

I want to generate random numbers between 0 to 8 without repeat any number. I use this code it works perfectly. But I want to remove goto statement from my code. how can i write my code without goto?
Thanks!!

Comment: Either `break` out of the inner loop, or use another loop nesting.

Comment: @sinsuren: You are wrong.  If you *just* break out of the inner loop, you will still assign to `randarr` and increment `i`

Comment: @Martinbonner i realized my mistake..thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to generate every number randomly. You want to shuffle the numbers from 0 to 8 in some random order.

A far simpler approach (that also eliminates the use of `goto`) is to start from a sorted array and pick an index to swap with randomly each iteration.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int randarr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    int swap_idx = rand() % 9;
    int temp = randarr[swap_idx];
    randarr[swap_idx] = randarr[i];
    randarr[i] = temp;
}
```

---

As noted by **HolyBlackCat**, the naive approach tends to give a non-uniform distribution of the various permutations. If that is a concern for you, an improvement is possible in the form of the [Fisher-Yates (or Knuth) shuffle](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2744-how-not-to-shuffle-the-kunth-fisher-yates-algorithm.html)

```
srand(time(NULL));
int randarr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    int swap_idx = i + rand() % (9 - i);
    int temp = randarr[swap_idx];
    randarr[swap_idx] = randarr[i];
    randarr[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite it using Fisher-Yates shuffle? This code seems to generate non-uniform distribution. http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2744-how-not-to-shuffle-the-kunth-fisher-yates-algorithm.html

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - So could the original one. I didn't set out to improve the quality of the distribution so much as the ease of implementation.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - But I added that note with attribution to you, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the other answer, this is a really terrible way to randomly select the numbers 0-8.  You should randomly shuffle them.

However, if you find yourself with a similar problem that seems to require a `goto`, you can always remove them by setting a flag.  So something like:

```
srand(time(NULL)); // Make sure you only execute this *ONCE* per program.
                   // Do not put it inside a function called repeatedly, or a loop.

for(i=0;i<9;) {
    int temp=rand()%9;
    bool matched = false;
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++) {
        if(temp==randarr[j]) {
            matched = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! matched) {
        randarr[i]=temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

It is a matter of taste whether this is easier or more difficult to read than the corresponding code with `goto`.  Personally, I am very happy using code like

```
     // acquire resources 
     ...

     // do work
     ret = function(...);
     if (ret) goto error:
     ....

     // release resources
 error:
     ....
     return ret;
```

But I would avoid jumping *backwards* (as your original code did).

Comment: A `goto` is permitted a) for error handling or b) to break out of nested loops. (a. is for languages that do not have structured error handling, such as C.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I very rarely find myself breaking out of nested loops, and it's often convenient to set some sort of flag anyway (or just `return`).  OTOH, when I'm coding in C, I pretty much *always* use goto for error handling.

Answer (score 1):

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    temp=rand()%9;
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(temp==randarr[j])
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    if(j > i) 
        randarr[i]=temp;
    else 
      i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- The condition in the inner loop should be `j < i` , randarr[i] is not yet assigned
- No need for indicator variables, you can detect the breaking out of the inner loop by `j != i` after the inner loop.

---

```
for(i=0; i < 9;) {
    int temp=urand(9);  /* to be supplied */
    for(j=0; j < i; j++ ) { /* Note j< i, *NOT* j<= i */
        if(temp==randarr[j]) break;
        }
    if ( j != i) continue; /* inner loop ended prematurely */
    randarr[i]=temp;
    i++;
    }
}
```

---

BTW: there isno need for the temp variable:

```
for(i=0; i < 9; ) {
    randarr[i] = urand(9);  
    for(j=0; j < i; j++ ) { 
        if(randarr[j] == randarr[i]) break;
        }
    if (j != i) continue; /* inner loop ended prematurely */
    i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
srand(time(NULL));
i = 0;
while(i < 9)
{
    temp = rand() % 9;
    int doesExist = 0;
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if(temp == randarr[j])
        {
            doesExist = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (doesExist == 0)
    {
        randarr[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }
    //printf("%d ",randarr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Didnt downvote but this is a quickfix in a code only answer